# undefined method `company_search' for LinkedIn API with linkedin-oauth2 gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, linkedin-api

I want to search companies with LinkedIn API in a Ruby on Rails project.

I use linkedin-oauth2 gem to do this but when I try any company search, I have this error.

```
undefined method `company_search' for #<LinkedIn::API:0x007f88aad68bb8>
```

This is my code:

```
api = LinkedIn::API.new(access_token)
@companies = api.company_search(
    keyword: "technologies", 
    facets: "location,industry", 
    facet: ["location,us","industry,4"], 
    start: 0, 
    count: 1000000
)
```

Comment: I don't see any method `company_search` documented in the gem

Comment: If you want to use it for your own use `gem 'linkedin-oauth2', git: 'emorikawa/linkedin-oauth2', branch: 'master'` in your Gemfile then bundle install

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the method(`company_search`) for your own use

```
gem 'linkedin-oauth2', github: 'emorikawa/linkedin-oauth2', branch: 'master'
```

in your  `Gemfile` then `bundle install`

but use a stable version of the gem as recomended

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you an using old version of this gem. This method was [added](https://github.com/emorikawa/linkedin-oauth2/commit/96aefd5696b1c075197e99c88e629019435a4710) in March 2015 and this gem is not released yet.

So, you should use latest version of gem from `master`:

```
gem 'linkedin-oauth2', github: 'emorikawa/linkedin-oauth2', branch: 'master'
```